# Does dedicated mode provide better results than fairshare in mid-circuit measurement?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I'm using a research account and I have a question about running circuits with (dedicated/priority mode) and without reservation (fair-share mode). From the documentation of dedicated mode,

> This (The dedicated mode) allows users to implement algorithms where input circuits are conditioned on previous results, such as iterative and near-time compute methods, without having to wait for other users’ results to process.

My quantum circuits involve mid-circuit measurements without resetting the qubit after it is measured each time, so each measurement is (kind of) dependent on the previous results. I wonder if I run them using the fair-share mode (without reservation), will that still give me the results I'm supposed to have from the dedicated mode? I have run some experiments and it looks like there aren't too many differences, but I'm not sure if there should or should not be. Thanks!

Comment: There should be no difference.

Comment: @Paul Nation Thank you!